# How to find controls inside a class with specific class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

Hello all I have a table as follows

```js
function checkAll2(rowClass, status) {
  var dynamicClass = $('.' + rowClass);
  // alert($('.1').find(":checkbox").length);
  alert($('input:checkbox.1').length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>1a:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1a" class="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1b:
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1b" class="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Select All/None above<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll2(1,this.checked)" />
```

But what I need is I would like to reuse this for different classes too so I will pass `rowClass` so that my `input:checkbox` should be appended with `rowClass` and give me the count or the list of controls with that class

Comment: `$('input:checkbox.'+rowClass).length`?

Comment: Thanks it is working

Comment: A better idea would be to use DOM traversal to find the child checkboxes related to the parent one. That way the HTML and JS is the same in all cases and you can expand/reduce the HTML structure without making any further changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the count of the `.1` classes this way for it to be "dynamic"

```js
function checkAll2(rowClass, status) {
  var dynamicClass = $('.' + rowClass);
  console.log($('input:checkbox.'+rowClass).length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>1a:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1a" class="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1b:
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="1b" class="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Select All/None above<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll2(1,this.checked)" />
```